# Netsuite Manage Intercompany sales order is not working

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, erp, accountmanager

I need help with intercompany transaction.

I have Subsidiary structure as per below

- Parent

  - Subsi L1 A

    - Subsi L2 A

      - Subsi L3 A
      - Subsi L3 B
      - Subsi L3 C
    - Subsi L2 B

Now, I need to generate intercompany Purchase and Sales between “Subsi L3 B” and “Subsi L2 B”.

I have created vendors and customers.

- Vendor1

  Primary Subsidiary   =   Subsi L3 B

  Represents Subsidiary =  Subsi L2 B
- Customer1

  Primary Subsidiary   =   Subsi L2 B

  Represents Subsidiary =  Subsi L3 B
- Vendor2

  Primary Subsidiary   =   Subsi L2 B

  Represents Subsidiary =  Subsi L3 B
- Customer2

  Primary Subsidiary   =   Subsi L3 B

  Represents Subsidiary =  Subsi L2 B

Now I have generate 2 Purchase orders, one with Vendor1 and one with Vendor2.

- Problem

When I goto “Manage Intercompany Sales Orders”, I can see both PO. But once I select any of the customer, both Purchase orders disappear from the list to get select.

Can anyone help, what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution. It was because of currency. Customer and vendor both must support the base currency. Here both belong to different subsidiary and both subsidiary holds different currency. I have added other currency to the Customer record and it works.

Thanks.